# I want to understand each captured column in Wireshark but there is no documentation

Tags: networking, wireshark

I want to understand each captured column in Wireshark but there is no documentation that I could understand. I captured the traffic for 3 days and saved it.
The columns >

```
print(df.columns)
Index(['StartTime', 'Dur', 'SrcDur', 'DstDur', 'Flgs', 'SrcAddr', 'Dir',
       'DstAddr', 'Proto', 'Sport', 'Dport', 'sTos', 'dTos', 'sTtl', 'dTtl',
       'sHops', 'dHops', 'TotPkts', 'SrcPkts', 'DstPkts', 'TotBytes',
       'SrcBytes', 'DstBytes', 'TotAppByte', 'SAppBytes', 'DAppBytes', 'Load',
       'SrcLoad', 'DstLoad', 'Rate', 'SrcRate', 'DstRate', 'Loss', 'SrcLoss',
       'DstLoss', 'pLoss', 'pSrcLoss', 'pDstLoss', 'SIntPkt', 'DIntPkt',
       'SIntPktAct', 'DIntPktAct', 'SIntPktIdl', 'DIntPktIdl', 'SIntPktMax',
       'SIntPktMin', 'DIntPktMax', 'DIntPktMin', 'SIPActMax', 'SIPActMin',
       'DIPActMax', 'DIPActMin', 'SIPIdlMax', 'SIPIdlMin', 'DIPIdlMax',
       'DIPIdlMin', 'SrcJitter', 'DstJitter', 'SrcJitAct', 'DstJitAct',
       'SrcJitIdl', 'DstJitIdl', 'State', 'SrcWin', 'DstWin', 'SrcTCPBase',
       'DstTCPBase', 'TcpRtt', 'SynAck', 'AckDat', 'sMaxPktSz', 'sMinPktSz',
       'dMaxPktSz', 'dMinPktSz', 'Label', 'Intrusion'],
      dtype='object')
```

I can understand some of them of course.

- StartTime > Date and Time of Day: 2022/03/19 05:31:32.835618 when the packet was captured
- SrcAddr: This is the address of the system that sent the packet.
- DstAddr: This is the address of the destination of that packet.
- Proto: This is the protocol of the packet, for example, TCP, UDP, DHCPv6, or ARP.

Any website you know?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other **off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) along with [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to print the column names and fields that comprise them.  For example:

```
tshark -G currentprefs | sed -n '/gui.column.format/,/^#/{/^#/!p}'
```